# Generate a code to each respondent after completing a form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am conducting a survey among students and I want to measure their attitudes on the beginning and end of the semester.

However, I want the survey to be anonymous.

My question is: Is it possible to create a script in Google Forms which will generate a unique code for each respondent, save that code in the Google Sheets alongside the responses and most importantly, provide the respondent with the code so that in the next round of survey, he/she can insert the code so that I can link the responses from the two surveys.

Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: There is no simple way to do this. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I agree with Rubén, that this generally takes several services working in tandem. However, see my proposed solution posted below.

Comment: This is exactly what i need... Have you ever figured it out on how to acomplish this? In my case i send forms to some phone numbers and i need to know if the person who answerd said "Yes" or "No."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). The workflow for getting such functionallity would be as follows:

1. Using [Form Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) every time a response is submitted generate a [random number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). If you want to track your codes so that two users don't end up with the same code (highly unlikely but possible) then store your codes with the responses in the Spreadsheet linked to your form using the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet), specifically take a look at the methods for [getting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and [setting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) values in a specific [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column). You can then compare your generated random number with the codes you already have and if it matches any generate a new random number and check again.
2. Either send this random number by email using [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail) or, in case it has to be completely anonymous set the submit message to display your code.

Then for providing a different form if the user already has an access code you can simply ask the user at the beggining of the form whether they have a code or they dont and depending on that [redirect them to the section](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en) of the form that you wish. To verify this code you could then on the form response compare his code with the list of codes you already have to verify that this user actually did complete the form previously.

Answer (score 0):

This generally takes several services working in tandem. However, an easy solution might be to have the first field on the form/survey simply ask the user to create and enter a codename for themselves, instructing them to save it (in their phone notes?) for use again at the end of the term. In fact, at the end of the term, you could even print out a full list of JUST the code names and post it for students to peruse, in case they forgot. Each person will certainly recognize the name they chose from a list, while no one else will know who's who. You could even ask them to submit the post-assessment right in class after checking the code name list. And actually, I'm sure most students will get a kick out of seeing (and wondering about) the weird code names that will turn up.